# Setting a personal backup server

Tags: backup, raid, nas

I am looking to set up a server to back up all my files from about 4 machines + phones. Can you recommend some systems for me to look at? Is it better to buy one or set up one my self?

What software do I have to run? I am thinking of running something like crashplan for the backup. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: I already have a linux server I run.

Thanks,

-P

Comment: What software does your machines run? Windows? (I'm guessing so). I'm a Linux fanboy, and for this, would setup a box and run nightly rsyncs. If you're not familiar with Linux, then you should look into rsync for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can consider rsync. It's cross platform, lightweight, and flexible. You can tweak it to get a [dropbox like backup](http://www.howtogeek.com/66348/how-to-setup-rsync-backups-on-linux-the-easy-way/), and if you are transferring huge files, you can configure rsynch to [use a preset bandwidth](http://www.howtogeek.com/50794/keep-rsync-from-using-all-your-bandwidth/) to save your self some capacity to do other things.